# Upload de foto com nome do Model no Django

Tags: python, django, crud, django-admin

## Gostaria de ajuda para uma tarefa de salvar imagens com um nome personalizado e uma pasta também com o nome corrente, suponha o seguinte Model:

```
class ProdutoA(models.Model):
    nome_produto_a = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nome do Produto')
    foto_produto_a = models.ImageField(upload_to='produtos', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Foto do Produto')
    # ...

class ProdutoB(models.Model):
    nome_produto_b = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nome do Produto')
    foto_produto_b = models.ImageField(upload_to='produtos', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Foto do Produto')
    # ...
```

## Minha dúvida:

Como salvar a imagem com o nome da classe "ProdutoX" + "nome_produto_x", ou seja, nome do model/classe a qual está cadastrada + nome do produto?

## Por exemplo, suponha que exista um produto cadastrado em ProdutoA:

nome_produto_a = Arroz 101

foto_produto_a = nomequalquer.jpg

## Ao salvar esta imagem, gostaria de renomear para:

ProdutoA.Arroz101.jpg

Dentro de uma pasta chamada de "Produto A".

## Resultando, portanto, em:

Produto A/ProdutoA.Arroz101.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Utilize um método no campo `upload_to`

documentação: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Veja o exemplo que envolve o método `user_directory_path`. Através da `instance` você tem acesso ao nome do modelo.